# How can I uncompress a PDF with Python only?

Tags: python, pdf

I currently want to manipulate strings in a PDF. As common Python libraries seem not support this, I uncompressed the PDF with `pdftk` and edited the file directly with Python.

Is there a possibility to uncompress a PDF file with Python directly?

Comment: What is the un-compress option in `pdftk`.  I quickly look at `pdftk` [link](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) could not find anything related compress / un-compress. I could find that it is just split, merge, rotate, watermark, stamp ... etc it is doing.

Comment: The command is `pdftk doc.pdf output doc.unc.pdf uncompress`. The description is "Uncompress PDF page streams for editing the PDF in a text editor (e.g., vim, emacs)"

Comment: Is that, before you edit your file, your input pdf file is part of `tar.gz` or `.zip` file? please share info.

Comment: Hey! did you try using [this](https://github.com/revolunet/pypdftk) lib?

Comment: @Haranadh No. I have a PDF file. But the content of many (most? all?) PDFs is compressed.

Comment: If you are OK with `pdftk` lib then I made a pull request for that lib. But there is no release. You can just use it. Follow below answer. If you are looking for other than pdftk, I didn't try to search.

Answer (score 2):

The most common cross platform "Decompressor" for editing is qpdf with its QDF mode. It does take a bit of getting used to it's syntax! ***Advantage over pdftk is it is fully open license.***

That is adapted to python using PyQpdf named more catch-ily as **PikePDF** see https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf

> A Python library for reading and writing PDF, powered by qpdf

However as OP Martin is now maintainer of PyPDF, he can pick which decompressive method that will use. Thus the docs say use above mentioned commercial pdftk see https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dev/pdf-format.html?highlight=uncompress#reading-pdf-files

Answer (score 0):

In the git-hub there was a new pull request for compress/uncompress. But it is not part of release.

You may want to copy --> paste the content of [pypdftk.py](https://github.com/revolunet/pypdftk/blob/master/pypdftk.py) to your local lib's `pypdftk.py` file. and just try using the following function.

```
import pypdftk

def test_compress():
    input_file = "/Out/test1.unc.pdf"
    pypdftk.compress(input_file, "./Out/test1.c.pdf")

def test_uncompress():
    input_file = "./Out/test1.pdf"
    pypdftk.uncompress(input_file, "./Out/test1.unc.pdf")

def main():
    test_num_pages()
    test_uncompress()
    test_compress()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Just gave a try. Not sure whether you are looking for same kind of solution. :) Hope this would help you.

Comment: This uses `pdftk`. It is almost identical to what I am currently doing (but worse, because it is a 3rd party module).

Comment: Yes. It is exactly same. But you could have mentioned in your post that you dont want pdftk solution.

Comment: I said "Python only" in the title.

Answer (score -1):

This code snippet works, decoded pdf can be processed by pdfrw while initially it gave error as

```
[WARNING] uncompress.py:46 Not decompressing: cannot use filter ['/ASCII85Decode', '/FlateDecode'] with parameters None
```

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import ContentStream, NameObject

pdf = PdfReader("compressed.pdf")
pdf_writer = PdfWriter()

for n in range(0, len(pdf.pages)):
    page = pdf.pages[n]
    content_object = page["/Contents"].get_object()
    content = ContentStream(content_object, pdf)
    page.__setitem__(NameObject("/Contents"), content)
    pdf_writer.add_page(page)
  
with open("decoded.pdf",mode="wb") as output_file:
    pdf_writer.write(output_file)
```

But Now, pdfrw breaks after installing pypdf2, specifically function

```
pdfrw.buildxobj.pagexobj
```

giving following error:

```
AttributeError: 'PageObject' object has no attribute 'inheritable'
```

Answer (score -4):

PyPDF2 can uncompress the contents object
Note: this is for PyPDF2 version 1.26 and before
(after that routine names were changed)

=====================================================

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF2 import generic
from PyPDF2.pdf import ContentStream
from PyPDF2.generic import TextStringObject, NameObject

pdf = PdfFileReader(in_name)  
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

for n in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
page = pdf.getPage(n)
    content_object = page["/Contents"].getObject()
    content = ContentStream(content_object, pdf)
    page.__setitem__(NameObject("/Contents"), content)
    pdf_writer.addPage(page)
  
with Path(out_name).open(mode="wb") as output_file:
    pdf_writer.write(output_file)
```